# Examine the given mapping for partial differentiability and provide the Jacobian matrix if it exists.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative

$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},
f(x, y) = \int_{0}^{y} \cos(t^2x) \, dt.$

I am facing difficulties in understanding the approach to solve this exercise.

I have tried reviewing my course materials and textbooks, but I am still unsure about the steps involved in analyzing partial differentiability and calculating the Jacobian matrix. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide guidance or insights into how to approach and solve this type of problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule helps with both variables.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Leibniz integral rule, allowed by the theorem of differentiability under the integral sign. It states under good conditions of the function that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt\right)=f(x,b(x))\cdot b'(x)-f(x,a(x))\cdot a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dt.$$ That's for the variable $x$, for the $y$ just apply the FTC. So $$f_y=\cos(xy^2),\,f_{yy}=-2xy\sin(xy^2),$$ and for $x$ we get $$f_x=\int_{0}^y -t^2\sin(t^2 x)dt,\,f_{xx}=\int_{0}^y -t^4\cos (t^2x)dx.$$ Now the crossed partials $$f_{yx}=-y^2\sin (xy^2),\, f_{xy}=-y^2\sin (y^2x),$$ which are equal, a good indicator that we did the things well.